# error when using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf, html

Hi: I've been trying to convert an html file on the web to a pdf and I've installed wkhtmltopdf based on the other links I found on askubuntu.

I did the steps below but it results in the error shown. I essentially copied an example from the man page.  I've never used this app before so if anyone know how I can use it correctly, it's appreciated. Thanks a lot. Oh, if anyone thinks it's better if I use something else, I'm open to doing that also.

```
echo "https://www.verywellhealth.com/migraine-shot-5218139 app.pdf" >> cmds

~/research/equity/projects/plate/temp_for_print> wkhtmltopdf --read-args-from-stdin < 
cmds

Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.

Error: This version of wkhtmltopdf is built against an unpatched version of QT, and does not support more than one input document.
```

Comment: Hello. Your question is missing the version of Ubuntu being used. That said this is quite an old tool and may not support what ever version of Ubuntu you are using. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `--read-args-from-stdin` and then not passing it any stdin. At best it'll hang then waiting for you to type some arguments. You might have meant `cat cmds | wkhtmltopdf --read-args-from-stdin`. But is there a reason not to just use `wkhtmltopdf "https://example.net/" output.pdf`?

Comment: @David: I'm using 21.10. I'll check out the link that you provided. Thanks.

Comment: @frabjous: You make a good point. It was on the man page but I didn't really know what I was doing. I'll try your suggestion and let you know. I'm not home right now so I can't try it immediately. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions. For future ubuntu users of wkhtmltopdf, the trick is to put both files in quotes seperately. So, the correct usage is wkhtmltopdf "html link" "output file.pdf". The man page is not that clear on this which is I'm writing it here. Thanks again.